# Issues with relationships in models

Tags: django, django-models

Let say i have one model named items which have following attribute name, size etc.
Now i wants that i specified these items attributes names in another table and there values in 3rd table.

So every time when i try upload any item it takes the value of there attributes specified in there respective tables....

I have tried it in following way

```
class item(models.Model):
    title           =models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True , null=True)
    image           =models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    size            =models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True , null=True)
    price           =models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True , null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return unicode(self.id)


class item_attributes(models.Model):
    item            =models.ForeignKey(Upload_files, blank=True , null=True)
    Name            =models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True , null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return unicode(self.product)

class item_values(models.Model):
    product         =models.ForeignKey(Upload_files, blank=True , null=True)
    attributes      =models.ForeignKey(Product_attributes, blank=True , null=True)
    value           =models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True , null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return unicode(self.product)
```

I hope that you understand my question , so please suggest me another easy way to do that

Comment: Why you do not store `value` of attribute as a field in the model `item_attributes`?

Comment: Read: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ after that check your FK's, their both pointing to Upload_files